# How to save a different default paper size for each of two/multiple printers?

Tags: printing

Using two printers. Would love to set e.g. the default paper size per printer. So when choosing either printer the correct size is chosen automatically. At the moment it seems that I have to decide (system-wide) for one size via system preferences > printers for all printers. I could define printer presets, of course, but that adds another click each time I choose a printer. Would love to choose A5 - Brother and the default is always A5, change to A4 - Brother with A4 as default.

Tried to change settings through CUPS web-interface, saved properly, but the change isn't reflected in the GUI.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can define Printer Presets that are specific to each printer. Then each one should be remembered as the 'current' setting for each print queue.

Comment: Printer presets are not remembered as the printers default preset, unfortunately. It always resets to standard preferences.

Comment: There is an option to reset to default or not in the Edit Preset List dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I know! It's not working the way one would think.